# What is a geometric construction corresponding to elliptic curve addition for Poncelet's Porism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

**Background**

At least since Griffiths and Harris [1] we know that the geometric construction "draw the next tangent" appearing in [Poncelet's Porism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem) corresponds to addition of a constant in the elliptic curve group. See [here](http://olivernash.org/2018/07/08/poring-over-poncelet/index.html) for some animations.

**The question**

A natural follow-up question seems to be that of the question title. More precisely, as highlighted [here](https://classes.golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/11/poncelets_porism.html), because of the dependence of choice of identity, we should probably study the natural ternary operation. Specifically, given a general pair conics $C, D \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, together with points $x_1, x_2, x_3$ in:
$$X = \{(p, l) \in C\times D^* ~|~ p \in l\},$$
is there a natural geometric construction corresponding to $x_1 - x_2 + x_3$? I'd even settle for some useful special case, e.g., when $x_2$ corresponds to one of the four points of $C \cap D$.

**Further waffle**

Thinking about this yesterday I decided that it might be worth looking for natural morphisms from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ since the divisors of such maps will give identities in the group operation. In a slightly-ridiculous thought experiment, I tried to put myself in the position of somebody with the data of a cubic in $\mathbb{P}^2$ who didn't know the "collinear iff sum to zero" rule for cubics in Weierstrass form but who did know there was a group law, and was searching for a geometric construction. At least in this setting, the idea to look for natural morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is fruitful since the ratio of two linear forms gives a map to $\mathbb{P}^1$. This gets you most of the way to the "Weierstrass rule", and you just have to spot that you should choose one of the two forms to define a line through an inflection point, which is then a natural identity.

However, try as I might, I couldn't come up with anything useful for $X$ in the Poncelet construction. For a *general* point $(p, l) \in X$ we have a natural isomorphism $l \simeq \mathbb{P^1}$ since there are three distinguished points on $l$:

- $p$,
- the other intersection point of $l$ and $C$,
- the point of tangency at $D$,

but this seems to be of no use. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[1] Griffiths, P., and Harris, J. "On Cayley's explicit solution to Poncelet's Porism", Enseign. Math., 24, 31–40 (1978).

Comment: I was wondering this myself while teaching a (somewhat) elementary geometry class.  I'm as stumped as you are.